# android toolbar back navigation not working as expected

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-toolbar

I have two activities A and B.

I have a mapview inside a fragment in activity A and on button click ,activity B is launched. The lifecyle goes like this:

```
onPause() in fragment inside A
onPause() in activity A

onStop() in fragment inside A
onStop() in activity A
```

When I press the physical back button on the device from activity B, it returns to activity A and the flow goes like this.

```
onStart() in activity A
onStart() in fragment inside A

onResume() in activity A
onResume() in fragment inside A
```

Now I have a custom toolbar set as actionbar using `setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)` in ActivityB. I have also set `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` for back navigation and it displays a left arrow.
The problem is that on click of left arrow,the activity A is getting recreated again.
The lifecycle goes like this:

```
onDestory() in fragment(in Activity A)
onCreate() in activity A
onCreate() in fragment
onCreateView() in fragment
onStart() in activity A
onStart() in fragment
onResume() in activity A
onResume() in fragment
```

And because of this, the map in activity A fragment is getting reloaded again.

Any can we prevent the fragment getting destryoed on back navigation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: this is very confusing to follow...you should try to clarify the flow

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried starting activity A using the *singleTop* launchMode? I ran into the same problem and specifying this launchMode for the calling activity solved my problem.

```
<activity
    android:name="A"
    android:label="..."
    android:launchMode="singleTop" />
```